# DBT - Segmentation Fault

Tags: dbt

When I try to use `dbt build` I'm getting this Segmentation Fault - I can't find a reason why:
[image]

Strangely `dbt run` seems fine. (now I get this error even with `run` command)

Here's an output with `--debug`

```
select *
from fields
      );
07:36:17.280015 [debug] [Thread-3  ]: Using snowflake connection "model.hubspot_source.stg_hubspot__engagement_task"
07:36:17.288681 [debug] [Thread-3  ]: On model.hubspot_source.stg_hubspot__engagement_task: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.1.1", "profile_name": "<profile>", "target_name": "development", "node_id": "model.hubspot_source.stg_hubspot__engagement_task"} */

    select completion_date from analytics_dev.dbt_dawid_stg_hubspot.stg_hubspot__engagement_task_tmp where completion_date is not null limit 1
07:36:17.887152 [debug] [Thread-3  ]: SQL status: SUCCESS 1 in 0.6 seconds
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: If you can reproduce this, I'd run with the `--debug` option for more logs and then open an issue in the dbt-core repo with as much detail as possible.  Seg faults happen because the C process that python calls out to tries to access memory it isn't allowed to -- so basically dbt is running out of memory on your machine. `dbt build` probably triggers it because there are many more steps than `dbt run` (assuming you have seeds and tests), but getting to the root cause will require more info from you (I've run `build` on projects with thousands of nodes with no problem)

Comment: Thanks for the details `dbt build --debug` returns `Uncrecognized arguments: --debug`

Comment: what about `dbt --debug build`?

Comment: it worked, I added the moment where the problem shows up. All models up until there are completely fine